# Multiple results in ? style if clause

Tags: ruby

I have the following code: `i ? "x" : "y"` But instead of only returning either "x" or "y" I also want to set i either true or false. `i ? ("x"; i = false) : ("y"; i = true)` however does not work.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(i ? "x" : "y").tap{i = !i}
```

or

```
(i = !i) ? "y" : "x"
```

But if this turns out to be an XY-situation (I don't write "XY-question" here because the OP has not asked any question), then this might be more elegant:

```
letter = ["x", "y"].cycle
letter.next #=> "x"
letter.next #=> "y"
letter.next #=> "x"
letter.next #=> "y"
...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return 'x' or y', then 'x' or 'y' needs to be the last statement:

```
i ? (i = false; 'x') : (i = true; 'y')
```

If you think of it like this, maybe it would make more sense:

```
if i
  i = false
  'x'
else
  i = true
  'y'
end
```

Keep in mind that setters in Ruby (and many other languages) return the value being set. For example, `i = false` returns `false`.

Comment: I wonder why people upvoted this wrong answer before the edit.

Comment: Maybe they missed it just like I did? Just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You should use ternary operator only in the simplest cases because readability and side-effect issues.

[Ruby Code Style](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-nested-ternary)

But if you really want it you could do something like this:

```
!(i = !i) ? 'x' : 'y'
```

Comment: A small tweak: `(i=!i) ? 'y' : 'x'`.